# Google script break line in string

Tags: javascript, html, string, google-apps-script, gmail

I’m trying to make a script that sends out an email to the whole company every morning. The issue I’ve run into is that I can’t manually break the line. For example:

“Hello,

I’m John”

Will output to:

“Hello,I’m John”

The script is basically done, so if anyone wants a functional script that sends out mass emails besides the break lines, then feel free to message me!

Comment: Use `\n\n` or `<br>`

Comment: Thank you! That worked!